# Need to create SQL query that calculates a field based on whether or not a linked record exists in a different table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm no database architect but my employer has saddled me with a problem that I'm not sure how to solve because I'm the "computer savvy geologist".

They have a database that has a table called "wellExpenses". In that table there are expenses that are linked to a table called "wellInvoices". They want me to create a query that provides the subtotal of a well subtracting the appropriate expense. However, There are not always expenses associated with each well.

So, while there may be 300 entries in the wellInvoices table, there are only about 75 entries in the wellExpenses table.

What I need to do is something like the psuedocode below:

```
If “wellNum” exists in “expenseTable”:
    “wellSubtotal” (in wellTable) = “wellSubtotal” (in wellTable) - 
    “expenseSubtotal” (in “expenseTable”)
Else:
    “wellSubtotal” (in wellTable) = “wellSubtotal” (in wellTable)
```

How would I do this in SQL? Or any other way in MS Access

Comment: Could you update your question with an example of the fields/data held by your `wellExpenses` and `wellInvoices` tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to advise without knowing the structure of your tables, but since your `wellExpenses` table may not necessarily contain a corresponding record for each record in your `wellInvoices` table, a `LEFT JOIN` from `wellInvoices` to `wellExpenses` would be appropriate - something like:

```
SELECT 
    wellInvoices.wellNum, 
    wellInvoices.wellSubtotal-Nz(wellExpenses.expenseSubtotal,0) AS wellTotal
FROM 
    wellInvoices LEFT JOIN wellExpenses ON wellInvoices.wellNum = wellExpenses.wellNum
```